# Declaring strings OUTSIDE the .data segment in nasm assembly

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, intel, nasm

Is there a way to define a string pointer in the `.text` part of the assembly code like this?

```
SECTION .text          

        global main             


main:                        
        fmt:    dd      "%s", 10, 0
```

or maybe have the string constructed and have a register pointing to it, put all of this could be done in the `.text` section?

Comment: Yes. And you probably could use also a `.rodata` section for read-only data.

Answer (score 1):

Assemblers are pretty dumb and you have to write all things explicitly, like this:

```
SECTION .text          

        global main             


main:                        
        ; Some code here, you don't want to execute data.

        mov     ebx, fmt ; ebx points to fmt[0] ('%')
        mov     eax, dword [pfmt] ; eax also points to fmt[0] ('%')

        ; Some more code here.

        pfmt    dd fmt ; pfmt is a constant pointer to fmt[0] ('%')
        fmt     db "%s", 10, 0 ; fmt is a constant string
```

You may be able to use macros to simplify coding:

```
%macro  LoadRegWithStrAddr 2+

        jmp     %%endstr
  %%str:        db      %2
  %%endstr:
        mov     %1, %%str

%endmacro

SECTION .text          

        global main             


main:                        
        LoadRegWithStrAddr ebx, "%s", 10, 0 ; ebx points to "%s\n"
```

`LoadRegWithStrAddr ebx, "%s", 10, 0` expands into:

```
        jmp     %%endstr
  %%str:        db      "%s", 10, 0
  %%endstr:
        mov     ebx, %%str
```

See NASM documentation.